# JS populate dropdown option with more than 1 attribute

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, geojson

I have JavaScript code that uses AJAX to call GeoJSON and PHP files to obtain info.

At present, the code works where the first function finds the user's current location, takes the lat/longs, and this is used to make an AJAX call to the CountryCodes PHP file to obtain the country code, which then can be used for adding the country border and information within the modals.

Following this, my navigation bar contains a dropdown of a list of all the countries.  Based on the option selected, the `countryName` is updated to reflect this as per `$('#innerSelect option:selected').val()`.

Basically, what I want to achieve is the population of the dropdown to also populate the option tags value attributes with iso_a2 codes (countryCode), so that I can read the country code from the dropdown.  But they don't need to be listed in the dropdown!  More so, associated with the country name in the background.

I should be getting an array of objects with country names and iso codes from a PHP routine, iterate over these elements and use the .append jQuery function to create the option tags.  The option values will be the iso alpha 2 codes, while the option text will be the country name.

Then when I call `countryName`, I can get `United Kingdom` but if I call `countryCode`, I get `UK`

```
let border;
let features;
let countryList = [];
let coords = [];



// ----- Load Leaflet Map at Users Current Location -----//

var map = L.map('map', {
    doubleClickZoom: false
}).locate({
    setView: true,
    maxZoom: 16
});


   if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
        const geoLocation = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

            map.panTo(new L.LatLng(position["coords"]["latitude"], position["coords"]["longitude"], ))
            let latitude = position["coords"]["latitude"];
            let longitude = position["coords"]["longitude"];
            console.log(latitude)
            console.log(longitude)

        $.ajax({
        url: "assets/php/getCountryCode.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            lat: latitude,
            lng: longitude
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.status.name == "ok") {
            $("#innerSelect").val(result['data']['countryName']).change();
            $("#innerSelect").val(result['data']['countryCode']).change();
            console.log(result['data']['countryCode'])
            }
            addCountryBorder(countryName);
            countryInfo(countryName);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.warn(jqXHR.responseText + "   " + errorThrown);
        }
    });

        });

    }

// ----- Find the coordinates of country polygon -----//

function findFeatureFromName(countryName) {
    let countryFeature = features.find((entry) => {
        return entry["properties"]["name"] == countryName;
    });
    return countryFeature;
}

// ----- Country Names for selection -----//
$(document).ready(() => {

    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
        const geoLocation = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

            map.panTo(new L.LatLng(position["coords"]["latitude"], position["coords"]["longitude"], ))

        });

    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/geojson/countryBorders.geo.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {},
        success: function(result) {

            $("#innerSelect").html(function() {
                    let newHTML = "<option id='firstOption'>Select </option>";
                    features = result["features"];


                    for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
                        countryList.push(features[i]["properties"]["name"]);
                    }

                    countryList.sort(); /* makes the country list alphabetical */

                    for (index in countryList) {
                        let country = countryList[index];

                        let nextOption = "<option value= '" + country + "' >" + countryList[index] + "</option>";
                        newHTML += nextOption;

                    }
                    return newHTML;

                }

            );

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    })

})


// ----- Functions called after selecting Country Name -----//

$('#innerSelect').on('change', async () => { 
    await addCountryBorder($('#innerSelect option:selected').val())
    countryInfo($('#innerSelect option:selected').val())
    getWeather($('#innerSelect option:selected').val())
    getAirQuality($('#innerSelect option:selected').val())
    getWikiSearch($('#innerSelect option:selected').val())
    getPark($('#innerSelect option:selected').val())
    getPOI($('#innerSelect option:selected').val())
});
```

Comment: its quite hard to tell what is happening at the moment and what you want to happen. I did notice that you have two `$("#innerSelect").val(...)` statements in your ajax success which doesn't seem correct. If you can update your question with a short and simple "this is what happens, this is what I want to happen" I think that would help